# One to one mapping is triggering N+1 queries

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to make an @OneToOne mapping following the https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ the mapping itself works but its triggering an N+1 query problem.

The query is being made on the parent entity service and its triggering  N+1 queries. 
**How can I improve this code to only make 1 query?** We don't need to access the ParentDetails in this case.

EDIT: I've tried using JPQL and `LEFT JOIN FETCH ParentDetails` and didn't work either.

EDIT2: Just to try to add more information. I've put a breakpoint on the getParentDetails just to make sure I was not calling the getter anywhere and I'm not calling and double-checked and it seems a join problem on the repo call.

Let's go to the code:

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Parent {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "parent")
   private ParentDetails parentDetails;

 // Getters, setters, etc omitted for brevity
}
```

**ParentDetails**

```
@Entity
public class ParentDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Parent parent;

    // Getters, setters, etc omitted for brevity
```

**ParentDetailsRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

    Page<Parent>findByNameOrderByName(@Param("name") final String name,final Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: What are the N+1 queries here? Do you have any output of that or can you turn on the hibernate property for dumping the queries?

Comment: I'm with the output turned on. For each `Parent` it's made a query on the `ParentDetails` table as well. I've also tested with `LEFT JOIN FETCH` on a JPQL query and didn't work either. Example: each page has 10 parents, it's made 11 queries. 1 on `Parent` and 10 on `ParentDetails`

Comment: Why are you using `@MapsId` ? As far as I know that is designed to work only with embedded primary keys (`@EmbeddedId`)

Comment: I think, in this case, what `@MapsId` is trying to do is to establish a relationship based on `ParentDetails` own Id. Do both Parent Id and ParentDetails Id match? For example, if Parent has id 47, does its ParentDetails id is 47 as well?

Comment: Suggestion on the Vlad Mihalcea website (I've shared the link on the post). On the ParentDetails the Primary Key is also a Foreign Key and it's called parent_id. Yes. ParentDetails doesn't have an Id, the common mapping (their id + parent_id has N+1 query issues as well, this is an attempt to improve that).

Comment: Try using a `@JoinColumn` with `parent_id` on the Parent entity, since you're using a different id name on ParentDetails (`parent_id`).

Comment: Just tested `@JoinColumn` on `Parent` and `ParentDetails` the same 1 + 10 queries :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213711/discussion-between-amportugal-and-ricardo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate executes the additional queries because the Parent entity doesn't map the foreign key column. Hibernate doesn't support lazy fetching for that end of the association. When Hibernate instantiates a Parent object, it needs to check if it needs to initialize the association with a proxy or a null object. And at some point, the team decided that they would fetch the associated entity if they are forced to perform a query anyways. I explained that in more detail here: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-lazy-loading-one-to-one

If you want to avoid the additional queries, you need to model a unidirectional association between ParentDetails and Parent. In your example, that would mean that you need to remove the parentDetails attribute from your Parent entity.

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Parent {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

 // Getters, setters, etc omitted for brevity
}
```

Because your ParentDetails entity uses the same id value as the Parent entity, you don't need a bidirectional association. If you want to get the ParentDetails entity for a Parent entity, you can get it with a call of the em.find(...) method

```
Parent p = // fetch the parent object ... 
ParentDetails pd = em.find(p.getId(), ParentDetails.class);
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer but nevertheless if you need the parent details info for mapping to a DTO or something it will trigger N+1. The JOIN FETCH doesn't work either. What are your takes on that?